# How to updateEmail and updatePassword firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I want to change the email (current user) from both authentication from realtime database(reference of the user so he/she can see her email). I read some documentation but it needs the password and here's the code:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

// Get auth credentials from the user for re-authentication
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
        .getCredential("user@example.com", "password1234"); // Current Login Credentials \\
// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
user.reauthenticate(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User re-authenticated.");
                //Now change your email address \\
                //----------------Code for Changing Email Address----------\\
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                //----------------------------------------------------------\\
            }
        });
```

Is there anyway on how do I get the password for the .getCredential part, 'cause in Email i can do user.getEmail() but I do not know how to get the password the account there's not user.getPassword();
the same goes to updatePassword. I'm kind of confused on how to do it.
btw here's my code for both updateEmail and updatePassowrd.

EditPasswordActivity

```
saveEditProfile_studentbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser studentUserEmail = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String replaceUserMail = studentChangeMail.getText().toString().trim();

        studentUserEmail.updateEmail(replaceUserMail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String studentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(studentUser);
                    String replaceName = studentChangeFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                    String replacePhoneNumber = studentChangePhoneNum.getText().toString().trim();
                    String replaceUserMail = studentChangeMail.getText().toString().trim();
                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                    updates.put("fullName", replaceName);
                    updates.put("phoneNumber", replacePhoneNumber);
                    updates.put("userEmail", replaceUserMail);

                    databaseReference.updateChildren(updates);
                    Toast.makeText(StudentProfileEditAct.this, "Changes has been made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(StudentProfileEditAct.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
});
```

EditPasswordActivity

```
changepassword_savechanges.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ( changeNewPassword.getText().toString().equals(changeReEnterNewPassword.getText().toString())){
            String newPassword = changeReEnterNewPassword.getText().toString().trim();
            FirebaseUser studentUser =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            studentUser.updatePassword(newPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(StudentEditPasswordAct.this, "Re-authenticated, Password has been changed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WelcomeStudentActivity.class));
                    }

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(StudentEditPasswordAct.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(StudentEditPasswordAct.this, "Password does not match, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            changeNewPassword.setText("");
            changeReEnterNewPassword.setText("");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to [change the password of a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#set_a_users_password), that user must have recently signed in with Firebase. If that requirement didn't exist, anyone could change any other user's password, which would be a serious security risk.

So the logic in the documentation on [re-authenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) is that you ask the user to enter their credentials again when they want to change their password, and then pass those credentials into the `EmailAuthProvider.getCredential()` call.